# MongoDB Custom sorting on two fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, nosql, mongodb-query

In our MongoDB document, we have two fields, *organisationId* and *employeeId*.

I want to show all the elements in a collection that have either of them matching the query parameters, so a basic OR.

One **condition for Sorting** is that I require is that the documents that have both the fields matching the query parameters should occur first, and then the documents matching *organisationName* parameter, next.

The idea is to show the data for the employee (i.e., you) first and then that of your organisation. (In our case topics suggested by you first and then by other employees in your organisation. 
As of now, I am using the following query to achieve this -

```
Campaigns.find({$and : [{'organisationName' : organisationName},{'employeeName' : userName}]},{}),
Campaigns.find({$and : [{'organisationName' : organisationName},{'employeeName' : {$ne : userName}}]},{})
```

But this does not seem like the most effective way to me. Any other query that can do this in just one call would be very nice, as that will help in the pagination too.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The solution would be, **add a new field for each doc** with `$addFields`, lets say `order` and with conditions using **`$cond and if`** adn other operators, assign it a value of 1,2,3,4.... based on conditions. And then **use `order` in `$sort` for sorting.**

Comment: I am not in favour for changing the data. The problem I can envision is that each org will have multiple employees, and each will have some topics by their id. We won't be changing these values for every search now.

Comment: No, you don't have to change the data, when you fire a query, then in the query only you have to add a new Field using $addFields and not in DB, and then use that in query only, no data is changed. And this filed will not be stored, so it just there till you send the result back, When some other employee does a search, there will be a new order filed created for him, It's just contextual and temporary and not permanent. Read here about $addFields https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/.

Comment: Oh Cool, I'll give it a shot, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Aggregation query gets the desired result:

**Input Documents:**

```
{ "org" : "o1", "emp" : "e1", "data" : "1234" }
{ "org" : "o1", "emp" : "e2", "data" : "abcd" }
{ "org" : "o1", "emp" : "b3", "data" : "xyz" }
{ "org" : "o2", "emp" : "z3", "data" : "zzz" }
```

**Query Parameters:**

```
orgNameParam = "o1"
usrNameParam = "e2"
```

**The Query:**

```
db.orgemp.aggregate([
  { $match: { org: orgNameParam} },
  { $facet: {
     firstQuery: [
          { $match: { emp: usrNameParam } }
     ],
     secondQuery: [
          { $addFields: { isNotEmp: { $ne: [ "$emp", usrNameParam ] } } },
          { $match: { isNotEmp: true } },
          { $project: { isNotEmp: 0 } },
          { $sort: { emp: 1 } },
     ],
  } },
  { $project: { result: { $concatArrays: [ "$firstQuery", "$secondQuery" ] } } },
])
```

**The Result:**

```
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc51432c2ac920e04692778"),
                        "org" : "o1",
                        "emp" : "e2",
                        "data" : "abcd"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc51432c2ac920e04692779"),
                        "org" : "o1",
                        "emp" : "b3",
                        "data" : "xyz"
                },
                {
                        "_id" : ObjectId("5dc51432c2ac920e04692777"),
                        "org" : "o1",
                        "emp" : "e1",
                        "data" : "1234"
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Yes, the input documents are passed thru the facet stage only once (and both queries are executed with the same set of data).