# How to separate a result in 2 fields

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am looking to find if a specific field is an Array or not. And return both in 2 distinct field. I am trying with a `$project` for now.

I would like to separate those 2 fields in a project as shown below. However I am stuck when it comes to divide the result. I am quite new on noSQL and I don't manage to have `"$value.FieldId"` which are array list in one field and all the `"$value.FieldId"` which are not array in the other field.

I want to perform an `$setunion` on the field `"value.FieldId"`. But `$setunion` only accept array type as an entry. And my `"value.FieldId"` is not always of array type, it's sometimes a simple string.

Therefor I need to split the two componeent of the `"value.FieldId"` in 2 distincts fields. In `isArray` all the `"value.FieldId"` which are of array type and in `isNotArray` all the `"value.FieldId"` which are not of array type.

```
   db.getCollection('collectionA').aggregate([
   {
      $project: {
         item: 1,
         matricule : "$value.id",
         isArray: {$isArray:"$value.FieldId"},
         isNotArray: {$isArray:"$value.FieldId"},
      }
   }
] )
```

If you have a lead or any advice for this situation it would be really helpfull.

Comment: You can try using [$facet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/index.html) as in this example: [MongoDb Exists per column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158391/mongodb-exists-per-column/59297724#59297724).

Comment: @Bruno : What do you mean by `stuck when it comes to divide the result` && also `array list in one field` + `which are not array in the other field` -- Do you mean by one doc & another document ? Do you want the value in field `isArray`, it would be ideal if you can edit your question to provide sample data & required o/p ?

Comment: @srinivasy I edited the question so it would be more understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `$setUnion` will only work if the given field is of type array in all documents of a collection, So please try this to make it work :

```
var inputArr = [7,8]
    db.CollectionA.aggregate(
       [
        {$project: {arr: {
                     $cond: { if: {  $isArray: "$arr"   }, then: { $setUnion: [ inputArr, "$arr" ] }, else: '$arr' }
                   }
               }
           }
       ]
    )
```

**Collection :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b596400289966e77e268"),
    "arr" : [ 
        1, 
        2, 
        3
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b5a0400289966e77e32e"),
    "arr" : [ 
        4, 
        5, 
        6
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b5a9400289966e77e3ee"),
    "arr" : 1
}
```

**Result :**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b596400289966e77e268"),
    "arr" : [ 
        1, 
        2, 
        3, 
        7.0, 
        8.0
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b5a0400289966e77e32e"),
    "arr" : [ 
        4, 
        5, 
        6, 
        7.0, 
        8.0
    ]
}

/* 3 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5df8b5a9400289966e77e3ee"),
    "arr" : 1
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your response. I did found a similar solution but my problem got bigger in the meantime. 
I am post an other question because your response does respond to the original question of this post.