# Sorting without considering null values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

In js with node js i want to sort result from model without considering document with nil values for example
Products = [
{_id:ObjectID(), priority:3},

{_id:ObjectID(), priority:1},

{_id:ObjectID(), priority:2},

{_id:ObjectID()}
]

So this mongo schema so i need a query to find sorted element witjout considering nil but documemts with nil values must be at the end of results in both ascending or deacending order

Comment: Hi @mathewsamir. Please provide an example output, and what you have tried to achieve such output. This will give a clarity on answering the best solution

Comment: For more clarification i already have data on product scema on production ,  new requirnment have comed to sort this product with new field named pirority ,  so now all object haven't this new properity so i need to make object with this field appear at begining and others appear at end

Comment: When i used sorted it came with result with nil then object has pirority 1 and piriority 2 so on i want pirority 1 to appear first then 2 then at end objects with no pirority field got it ?!

Comment: Here is an answer for a similar question (a SO post): [MongoDB Custom Sorting on two fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58760718/mongodb-custom-sorting-on-two-fields/58762464#58762464)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here is an example assuming your data is in a collection called "products".  Here we assume the null value is expected to sort at the end of the results.  Also, it is assumed you wish to sort priority in an ascending fashion.

I use an arbitrary large number - 999999 - to represent null values and sort by that value.

**Aggregation**

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        $addFields:
        {
            "sortField":
            {
                $ifNull: [ "$priority", 9999999 ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $sort: { "sortField": 1 }
    },
    {
        $project: { "sortField": 0 }
    }
])
```

**Results**

```
[
  { _id: ObjectId("61b0e373c6c466d7d1ea9b5b"), priority: 1 },
  { _id: ObjectId("61b0e373c6c466d7d1ea9b5c"), priority: 2 },
  { _id: ObjectId("61b0e373c6c466d7d1ea9b5a"), priority: 3 },
  { _id: ObjectId("61b0e373c6c466d7d1ea9b5d") }
]
```